# Why is my java path not being recognized?

Tags: java, environment-variables

Why is the javac.exe not being recognized?  I should have the right path in my environment variable.  Anyone have any clues?  I've already restarted the computer after editing my environment variables, so it should be updated.  Thanks!
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try losing the spaces in the Path setting - ie the "; C:..." spaces. I've had problems with this placement of a space in paths before.

Comment: definitely that space before the C is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searched many answers that suggest me to type in cmd:

```
set path = "%path%;c:program files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin"
```

but this is WRONG!

**the right solution** is that you leave "set" and just type

```
path = "%path%;c:program files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin"
```

*P/s: of course you have to replace "jdk1.7.0" folder by your current java version folder*